# How to add text with zoom out effection on video in FFMpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am developing android app with ffmpeg.
I`d like to add text on video and set the zoom out animation on it.
I can marquee the text from bottom to top and from left to right.
If someone has experiences on zoom out animation of text with FFMpeg, please give me the tip.
Here is my code.

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf: text ='Test Line':fontcolor=red:fontsize=65:x=100: y=if(lt(t\,8)\,30*t\,240)" output.mp4

Comment: fontsize can be animated using the same variables as x and y

Comment: if the font size is animated then it will create jerky text. how to solve that issue? @Gyan